# flowtype error with react's synthetic event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am actually trying to learn flowtype.
In my react app I have a reusable TextArea component, this is the props declaration:

```
type props = {
  fill?: boolean,
  large?: boolean,
  blue?: boolean,
  red?: boolean,
  onChange: (
    e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement> & { currentTarget: HTMLInputElement },
  ) => void,
  value: string
};
```

when I reuse it in an other component:

```
<TextArea value={this.state.note} onChange={this.changeNote} />
```

the changeNote method:

```
  changeNote = (
    e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement> & { currentTarget: HTMLInputElement },
  ) => {
    this.setState({ note: e.currentTarget.value });
  };
```

I get this error when running flow:

```
app/components/pages/bills/BillAddPage.js:256
256:           <TextArea value={this.state.note} onChange={this.changeNote} />
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ React element `TextArea`
 21:     e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement> & { currentTarget: HTMLInputElement },
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ intersection type. Expected polymorphic type instead of. See: app/components/atoms/TextArea.js:21
141:     e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement> & { currentTarget: HTMLInputElement },
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ class type: SyntheticEvent
```

What's wrong about that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a specific `SyntheticEvent` instead, like `SyntheticInputEvent`.

- `SyntheticEvent<T>` for Event
- `SyntheticAnimationEvent<T>` for AnimationEvent
- `SyntheticCompositionEvent<T>` for CompositionEvent
- `SyntheticInputEvent<T>` for InputEvent
- `SyntheticUIEvent<T>` for UIEvent
- `SyntheticFocusEvent<T>` for FocusEvent
- `SyntheticKeyboardEvent<T>` for KeyboardEvent
- `SyntheticMouseEvent<T>` for MouseEvent
- `SyntheticDragEvent<T>` for DragEvent
- `SyntheticWheelEvent<T>` for WheelEvent
- `SyntheticTouchEvent<T>` for TouchEvent
- `SyntheticTransitionEvent<T>` for TransitionEvent

Ref: https://flow.org/en/docs/react/events

Comment: thank you MichaelDeBoey, I edit your answer to show the solution